# How to make this function stop at N characters/

Tags: c++, loops

So I have this assignment which is to take the contents of one text file and copy it to another. We have to rewrite the strncpy default function, but slightly different. Here's what the lab write up states explicitly:

> *This function replaces the std::strncpy function. That is, it copies the content of s2 to s1 but no more than N characters. Hint: Since
>   strlength (and std::strlen) doesn't count the null-terminating
>   character, remember to add increment that number by one when calling
>   strncopy (and std::strncpy). To avoid producing a segmentation
>   violation, you must check if the null-terminating character has been
>   encountered before you dereference s2 to copy the data to s1. Again,
>   base your code on a pointer loop.*

Here's what I have so far for my function:

```
void strncopy(char *s1, const char *s2, int N){

    // return if no memory is allocated to the s1
    if (s1 == NULL)
       NULL;

    // take a pointer pointing to the beginning of s1 string
    char *ptr = s1;

    // copy the C-string pointed by s2 into the array
    // pointed by s1
    while (*s2 != '\0'){

        if (*s1 == N){
            break;
        } 

     //   *s1 = *s2;
        s1++;
        s2++;

    }

    // include the terminating null character
    *s1 = '\0';
}
```

The problem that it appears to have is the loop is not stopping when it reaches N amount of characters.

Here's the bit of my main function implementing this function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


  // check for four command line arguments
  // if not, print error message and bail out
    if (argc != 4){
        cerr<<"Error";
        return -1;;
    }

 // declare two streams: file1, file2
   fstream file1;
   fstream file2;

 // declare two char text line arrays
    char textline1[256];
    char textline2[256];

  if (strcompare(argv[1], "-copy") == 0) {
    //open file1 for reading
      file1.open(argv[2]);
      //open file2 for writing
      file2.open(argv[3]);

            //read text line 1 frome file1
      while (file1.getline(textline1, 256)) {
      // determine length of textline1
      char t1 = strlength(textline1);
     // copy textline1 to textline2
        strncopy(textline2, textline1, (t1+1));
     // write textline2 + newline to file2
        file2 << textline2 << '\n';
    }
  }
```

Here's the text in the file I'm trying to copy:

> Captain's log, stardate 3192.1. The Enterprise is en route to star
>   cluster NGC 321.  Objective, to open diplomatic relations with the
>   civilisations known to be there.  We have sent a message to Eminiar
>   Seven, principal planet of the star cluster,  informing them of our
>   friendly intentions. We are awaiting an answer.

And here's what I'm actually copying:

> Captain's log, stardate 3192.1. The Enterprise is en route to star
>   cluster NGC 321.  Objective, to open diplomatic relations with the
>   civilisations known to be there.  We have sent a message to Eminiar
>   Seven, principal planet of the star cluster,  informing them of our
>   friendly intentions. We are awaiting an answer. n answer.cluster, .

Does anyone know what my problem is?
I'm sorry this is a dumb question, but ever since classes went to online only, its getting really difficult to get help from instructor and TAs.

Comment: Consider: where in your loop are you counting characters?

Comment: Hint: Add another condition to your `while` loop.

Comment: The only thing I can think to add to the while loop is while (*s2 != '\0' && *s1 ==N), but that isn't working.

Comment: Why are you trying to compare s1 to N?  What makes you think that is a count?

Comment: Well, s1 is the destination. So I want the loop to stop when the file being written to reaches length N. Am I not correct in that logic?

Comment: Yes, but s1 doesn't contain the length. Writing an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you have the following to check the length:

```
if (*s1 == N){
    break;
}
```

However, since `s1` wouldn't contain the length in it (presumably), you are comparing the characters in `s1` to `N`, which will likely be false (but is UB if `s1` was not initialized).

You can modify your `while` condition like so:

```
while (*s2 != '\0' && N--)
```

When `N` reaches 0, it's condition will be false, and hence stop the loop. This assumes that `N` is greater than or equal to zero to begin with.

Also, to add, you have

```
// return if no memory is allocated to the s1
if (s1 == NULL)
    NULL;
```

This does not return, it actually does nothing. You want to do the following:

```
if ( s1 == NULL )
    return;
```

PS: You may want to consider using `nullptr` instead of `NULL` if you're using C++11 or later.